# Wiql azure devops query to track work items in state "Blocked" during some period

Tags: azure-devops, wiql

I need to track items being in a particular state during a particular period of time.
There is wiql:

```
SELECT
    [System.Id],
    [System.WorkItemType],
    [System.Title],
    [System.AssignedTo],
    [System.State],
    [Custom.Hurdle],
    [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate],
    [System.IterationPath]
FROM workitems
WHERE
    [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story'
    AND [System.AreaPath] UNDER 'AREA'
    AND [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate] >= ITERATION_START_DATE
    AND [System.State] EVER  'Blocked'
    AND [System.IterationPath] = 'ITERATION_NAME'
```

It returns items ever being in state "Blocked" and where in the particular iteration. There are few issues with that:
1. item could be in blocked few months ago, unblocked month ago and put in particular iteration, which is not relevant
2. item could be changed to state "Blocked" and ther removed from a particular iteration.
Is there any way in Azure Devops to retrieve work items that were in some state during a particular timeframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way in Azure Devops to retrieve work items that were in
>   some state during a particular timeframe?

For now there's no out-of-box feature to support this scenario. What you want is similar to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#list-items-based-on-the-contents-of-the-history-field):

```
State Was Ever Closed
And Closed Date > 7/1/2015
And Closed Date <= 7/21/2015
```

However the existing fields are`Accepted Date, Activated Date, Changed Date, Called Date, Created Date, Resolved Date, Closed Date...`, we don't have the `'Blocked Date'` for your scenario.

So I'm afraid what you want is not supported yet cause Azure Devops Service doesn't support `Blocked Date` for your custom state `Blocked`.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), this is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope it helps to resolve your puzzle :)